# Чтение данных c firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Вопрос следующий. Создаю post через FB. И хочу добавлять избранные с помощью добавления child в пост, который равен UID. `DatabaseReference dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(newPost.getCat()+"0"); dRef.child(newPost.getKey()).child("Datadata2/favorite"+mauth.getUid).setValue(mAuth.getUid());`

Есть структура и в нее я отдельно добавляю эти child.  С этим все хорошо, как мне теперь прочитать конкретно этот child. Точнее не прочитать, с этим тоже проблем нет, а именно сравнить. То есть, проверить чему этот child equals.